# how to get rid of the white strips or blank strips in the heatmap raster image rendered in R?

Tags: r, raster

"ComplexHeatmap" was used to plot a heatmap for two 20000x100 matrices

#### code

g3 = Heatmap(dat_1,name = "multiscale_F",show_row_names = F,  col=colorRamp2(c(-0.2, -0.1, -0.01, 0, 0.01,  0.1, 0.2),   c("darkblue", "blue", "white","white", "white", "red", "red4")), na_col="black",cluster_rows = F, cluster_columns = F, use_raster = T,  show_column_names = F,row_dend_reorder = FALSE,column_dend_reorder = F,cluster_column_slices = FALSE)

```
    g4 = Heatmap(dat_2,name = "multiscale_M",show_row_names = F,  col=colorRamp2(c(-0.2, -0.1, -0.01, 0, 0.01,  0.1, 0.2),  c("darkblue", "blue", "white","white", "white", "red", "red4")), na_col="black",cluster_rows = F, cluster_columns = F, use_raster = T,  show_column_names = F,row_dend_reorder = FALSE,column_dend_reorder = F,cluster_column_slices = FALSE)
```

library("zoo")
svg('chr8.MF_purple.test_change_color.09.14.2023.new.1.svg',width = 3, height =8)
draw(g3+g4)
dev.off()

The resultant svg image have artificial trips in the middle.   I find, incease or decrease the size of the image may mitigate the trips,but I am wondering what's the reason and is there a better way to handle this?
[image]